# Optimal size of std::map

Tags: c++, stdmap, pow

I am using `std::map` key is 2 double pair and value as one double value.

I am using it to cache power values.

My question is at what size of map (cache) I can say like searching/insertion will take more time than calculating power and I should clear it.

Comment: I have 5 million calls to pow functions 24,000 are unique calls and I want to reduce it.

Comment: I think there is no answer to that question. The performance of your map hardly depends on how you use it, on which platform your run your code, etc.. To make your map run as fast as possible, you wont get around of bench marking your code.

Comment: your map won't work as expected no matter how many elements are inside. Using `double`s as keys can and will lead to problems

Comment: @idclev463035818 if the only purpose is chaching, I do not see a huge problem in using doubles as key. It still hardly depends on the usecase.

Comment: I am open for suggestions for  "5 million calls to pow functions 24,000 are unique calls" problem. And unique I mean unique uptill floating point precision.

Comment: @JulianH it can be used without problems but one needs to be aware that it won't work like one epxects from a "normal" `std::map`

Comment: it depends. if you have code that calls the same function with same parameters ~100 times then I would first try to fix that code rather than the function. Memoization also has a cost. Not calling the function for same parameters over and over again is for free. Can you post a [mcve] ?

Comment: @HimanshuSaxena your question is hard to answer since the answer depends on too many factors like: Input distribution, platform your code is running on and so on.

Comment: depending on platform, if that's any modern platform, pow isn't a function but alias for an intrinsic, i.e. for CPU instruction to perform that calculation. There are possible optimizations to reduce amount of calls, cache intermediate values, use streaming instructions, replace pow by its equivalent if precision allows - but that requires change of code structure. The search in map is absolutely slower and got less locality than intrinsic call, adding new value is moreso. Make sure that you use <cmath> instead of <math.h>

Comment: the search in table of known values is ALREADY implemented in CPU and in better way than map does, essentially it's reference values and interpolation between them and it's done in hardware. ALl what you'd want is to avoid excess cache invalidation or to get advantage of performing several operations at once using streaming operations (SSE, AVX for Intel arch, NEON for ARM, etc.)

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie interesting, on my Intel i9900ks `std::pow` is not translated to an instrinsic. So what kind of "modern architecture" you are talking about?

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie what will change with  using <cmath> instead of <math.h>.

Comment: Just to add another point that for data I am getting for pow, map cache reduces time considerably. Bringing down from ~17 secs to under 2 secs on Linux platform.

Comment: So which size are you using?

Comment: @HimanshuSaxena sounds like you have use-case where exactly  same calculations (same values) used over and over again

Comment: @JulianH really depends on compiler and generation in case of x86..newer processors do poorly with FPU opcodes, instead MS compiler implemented so that it links a library function, which one , depends on the command-line options. E.g. in that cpu using SSE or AVX opcode for sine function is faster and more precise than fsin opcode. Say thanks to targeted optimization of hardware (even one of former MS devs said that Intel's optimization is BS).

Comment: @JulianH "intrinsic" function is a built-in function  provided by implementation, whether inlined or not, but it implied that it's a fast, minimalistic function without extra bells and whistles (stack unwinding, standard ABI requirements, parameter and result checking avoided). For x86 platform a lot of those can be subject of Intel copyright and compilers that aren't Intel have to use library. ALso in case on MSVC there are subtle differences if /Oi is used or not. With /Oi they use simpler functions but do not inline them. For other platforms it might not be case

Comment: @HimanshuSaxena they can be implemented differently from C version (latter  are required to do things like setting errno). FOr MSVC that'd be using /Oi, headers are identical. If you use g++ version of library, some math functions are constexpr, which lets you not to worry if you have `pow(constant, constant)`, or `pow(constant, variable)` - if latter is the case, why you use `pow`?. But that's not standard implementation. Formally use of math.h may lead to UB, but most implementations avoid it.